# How to handle unexpected iframe ads in Selenuim webdriver(java)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to handle the unexpected iframe ads in my code. I know the below code(from SOF) can handle the iframe at an expected time.

```
driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(By.id(locatorToIdentifyFrame)));       
driver.findElement(By.id(locatorToCloseAd)).click(); //Close Ad
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // Return to main window
```

- But my problem scenario is

I completely have no idea of when the iframe ad is going to pop-up. it can happen anytime during my execution. It may even not appear some time. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the iframe is present and act on it. For  instance after every menu click you check of the iframe with ads is there. If it is, just close it.

Comment: I thought about that, but then I feel that is unnecessary code throughout my execution if the ads doesn't pop up. I am looking if there is any even optimal solution to this. Thanks for writing anyways!